# Why are there so many random generators in R?

Tags: r, random-generation

A quick look at the [help page](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Random.html) of the random number generator of R shows that you can choose among 7 predefined generators (`Wichmann-Hill`, `Marsaglia-Multicarry`, `Super-Duper`, `Mersenne-Twister`, `Knuth-TAOCP-2002`, `Knuth-TAOCP`, `L'Ecuyer-CMRG`).

```
?Random
```

The default is [Mersenne-Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister), which seems to be very good. So why would you ever need to use another one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One case where this RNG cornucopia is handy is when you're rewriting or comparing software that rely on different RNGs. One example might be porting R code to C++. You want to pin down why you're getting different results and it helps to hold as many things constant as possible.